# Coherent logs from multiple identical nodes

Tags: log-files, cluster

I have multiple web heads running a stack containing Apache/mod_php/Magento/MySQL and more. Every time I need to view logs I find myself jumping on multiple servers to view logs in different files until I find the right one. Magento logfiles don't adhere to a specific standard, either.

Ideally I would like to have an interface similar to `tail -f` that can handle changes to multiple files at once. Is there a general solution for this problem that can handle many different formats of logfile? What do you do to view standard and nonstandard log files on multiple identical nodes in a cluster?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [Splunk](http://www.splunk.com/), we use it for exactly this kind of thing, and more.

Oh and by the way, we don't do shopping questions on here - as I'm sure you saw when you read our FAQ ;)

Comment: It would help me to understand why you think my question is *shopping*. I had rather thought I was asking for a simple way to tail a logfile interlaced across multiple servers, but you seem to think I'm asking for an enterprise graphical monitor and log analyzer (orders of magnitude more complex than what I thought I was asking). Where lies the disconnect?

Comment: @kojiro Splunk is probably the Right Tool for your needs (try it out and you'll see why) -- Your question is asking `What do you do to view standard and nonstandard log files on multiple identical nodes in a cluster?`, and the answer (for most of us) is `Some centralized logging software (syslog-ng ; rsyslog) to collect it all, and Splunk to view it.`